# Reindexing error within np.where and for loop

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, indexing, astronomy

I have a large CSV table with ~1,200 objects. I am narrowing down those to a volume limited sample (VLS) of 326 objects by setting certain parameters (only certain distances, etc.)
Within this VLS I am using a for loop to count the number of specific types of objects. I don't want to just count the entire VLS at once though, instead it'll count in "sections" (think of drawing boxes on a scatter plot and counting what's in each box).

I'm pretty sure my issue is because of the way pandas reads in the columns of my CSV table and the "box" array I have can't talk to the columns that are "dtype: object."

I don't expect someone to have a perfect fix for this, but even pointing me to some specific and relevant information on pandas would be helpful and appreciated. I try reading the documentation for pandas, but I don't understand much.

This is how I read in the CSV table and my columns in case it's relevant:

```
file = pd.read_csv(r'~/Downloads/CSV')
#more columns than this, but they're all defined like this in my code
blend = file["blend"] 
dec = file["dec"]
```

When I define my VLS inside the definition of the section I'm looking at (named 'box') the code does work, and the for loop properly counts the objects.
This is what it looks like when it works:

```
color = np.array([-1,0,1])

for i in color:
    box1 = np.where((constant box parameters) & (variable par >= i)& 
  (variable par < i+1) &('Volume-limited parameters I wont list'))[0] 
    binaries = np.where(blend[box1].str[:1].eq('Y'))[0]
    candidates = np.where(blend[box1].str[0].eq('?'))[0]
    singles = np.where(blend[box1].str[0].eq('N'))[0]
    print ("from", i, "to", i+1, "there are", len(binaries), "binaries,", len(candidates), "candidates,", len(singles), "singles.")

# Correct Output:
"from -1 to 0 there are 7 binaries, 1 candidates, 78 singles."
"from 0 to 1 there are 3 binaries, 1 candidates, 24 singles."
"from 1 to 2 there are 13 binaries, 6 candidates, 69 singles."
```

The problem, is that I don't want to include the parameters for my VLS in the np.where() for "box". This is how I would like my code to look:

```
vollim = np.where((dec >= -30)&(dec <= 60) &(p_anglemas/err_p_anglemas 
                            >= 5) &(dist<=25) &(err_j_k_mag < 0.2))[0]

j_k_mag_vl = j_k_mag[vollim]
abs_jmag_vl = abs_jmag[vollim]
blend_vl = blend[vollim]
hires_vl = hires[vollim]

#%%
color = np.array([-1,0,1])

for i in color:
    box2 = np.where((abs_jmag_vl >= 13)&(abs_jmag_vl <= 16) & 
                            (j_k_mag_vl >= i)&(j_k_mag_vl < i+1))[0] 
    binaries = np.where(blend_vl[box2].str[:1].eq('Y'))[0]
    candidates = np.where(blend_vl[box2].str[0].eq('?'))[0]
    singles = np.where(blend_vl[box2].str[0].eq('N'))[0]
    print ("from", i, "to", i+1, "there are", len(binaries), "binaries,", len(candidates), "candidates,", len(singles), "singles.")

#Wrong Output:
"from -1 to 0 there are 4 binaries, 1 candidates, 22 singles."
"from 0 to 1 there are 1 binaries, 0 candidates, 5 singles."
"from 1 to 2 there are 4 binaries, 0 candidates, 14 singles."
```

When I print blend_vl[box2] a lot of the elements for blend_vl have been changed from their regular strings to "NaN" which I do not understand.

When I print box1 and box2 they are the same lengths but they are different indices.

I think blend_vl[box2] would work properly if I changed blend_vl into a flat array?

I know this is a lot of information at once, but I appreciate any input. Even if just some more info about how pandas and arrays. TIA!!

Comment: It definitely appears that your complicated Where clauses are changing the dimensions/shape which you may be expecting at intermediate steps.  This could cause NaN values in your output. I'd recommend printing shape values at each line, as a debugging exercise.

Comment: So changing all of my [ ] indexing (blend_vl[box]) to blend_vl.iloc[box] seemed to have done the trick, at least for now